# Can we write this code in different way by using list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Any other optimize way to write the below code

```
t1=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    x=int(input())
    t1.append(x)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize" here? Have you tried to write a list comprehension?

Comment: Can we write the code in single line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for

```
t1 = [int(input()) for _ in range(10)]
```

which does the same thing but does not optimize the code in any meaningful way. While list comprehensions might be faster than for-loops, this doesn't matter when your code has to wait for user input. Furthermore: You probably have to do some input checking/parsing (What happens if the input cannot be cast to an integer?) and this really shouldn't be done inside a list comprehension.